# Get the environment variable address

Tags: c, gdb

I have ASLR disabled. Well, I want obtain the address of the environment variable "SHELL", so I use the C function getenv().

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char* ptr = getenv("SHELL");
    printf("%p\n", ptr);
}
```

The address obtained with getenv()

```
$ ./getenv
0xbffff752
```

The address obtained with gdb:

```
gdb> x/4000s $esp
...
(gdb) x/s 0xbffff710
0xbffff710:     "SHELL=/bin/bash"
(gdb) x/s 0xbffff716
0xbffff716:     "/bin/bash"
```

Why are the addresses different? As noted, I must say the correct address in the obtained with GDB.

Comment: How do you know that the correct address is with gdb? Surely both are correct

Comment: Both are living in different environments.

Comment: @EdHeal If I search with the address obtained with the C function: (gdb) x/s 0xbffff752
0xbffff752:  <Address 0xbffff752 out of bounds>

Comment: the posted code does not even begin to compile.   amongst other things, '#include <stdlib.h>'  is needed for the system function; getenv().   Strongly suggest compiling with all warnings enabled.  (for gcc, at a minimum use: '-Wall -Wextra -pedantid')

Comment: on my system (ubuntu linux 14.04) the posted code, after adding missing #include, outputs: 0x7fff2280de16
and gdb outputs: 0x7fffffffe46a   Amongst other things, these are different processes, each with its' own address space, so the 'effective' address of the same environment variable are different

Comment: @user3629249 Ok, thanks. I've added stdlib.h, but the address is the same.

Comment: @user3629249: Many C implementations will manage a missing prototype very well, if the function's implementation returns a value with a bitwidth of `int`.

Comment: @alk But in the printf I have "%p", no "%i". Is it not correct?

Comment: You probably are on a 32bit platform?

Comment: @alk Yes, on a 32-bit platform.

Comment: What method did you use to disable ASLR?

Comment: Note that the length of the name of the program being executed seems to have an effect on the address of the environment variables.

Answer (score 6):

> Why the addresses are different?

Because one is run under `gdb` and one isn't.  Running under a different environment results in a different environment.  Literally.

What's the output of the `printf()` statement when running under `gdb`?

> As note, I must say the correct address in the obtained with gdb.

What information is that statement based on?

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is that your list of environment variables can differ when running under gdb and without it.  And that is enough to cause the shift in address.

Somewhat shortened listing... (your program)

```
$ gdb ./a.out
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/mfranc/a.out 
0x7fffffffdd37
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/mfranc/a.out 
0x7fffffffdd37
(gdb) set environment a="hello world"
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/mfranc/a.out 
0x7fffffffdd27
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/mfranc/a.out 
0x7fffffffdd27
(gdb) unset environment a
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/mfranc/a.out 
0x7fffffffdd37
(gdb)
```

Generally you should debug in the original environment and attach to the process via gdb -p $PID. If you spawn process in a slightly different way and the environment will differ slightly you might see different addresses.

Comment: mm, as you and @user3629249 says, the addresses are different because my program is running under gdb. I understand a debugger debug a process, but the process is independent (it's a "normal" process) and gdb only stop, modify, etc. it. What is exactly what happened? gdb doesn't add environment variables.

Comment: @David The thing that has happened is that when doing gdb ./program gdb is the parent of your process. If you want absolute independence you need to debug in the original environment and attach to the process via gdb -p $PID.

Comment: Ok, ok. Can I not run the program and create the process for attach after with gdb? As a normal debug with gdb, I want say. I want test that.

Comment: For a program that finishes too quickly the only way I can think of is to put getchar (); to cause it wait for you.

Comment: I added a getchar at the first line in main(). Ok, $ ./getenv prints 0xbffff752, and if I use "gdb -p myPID", (gdb) x/s 0xbffff750, 0xbffff750:  "/bin/bash". getenv.c prints to 0xbffff752 and gdb to 0xbffff750. It's not the correct address anyway.

Comment: @David Which does not make much sense, since the addresses differ by 2 bytes. Sorry, I'm not entirely sure what, but you must be doing something wrong. It works for me.

Comment: using a source in a book I bought, I obtain the correct addres. I don't see the logic. argv[1] must be "SHELL" and argv[2] is the name of the executable to  debug. Source:
ptr = getenv(argv[1]); ptr += (strlen(argv[0]) - strlen(argv[2])) * 2;

Answer (score 0):

[For Linux]

From [`man 3 getenv()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html) (*italics* by me):

> The implementation of getenv() is not required to be reentrant.  *The
>          string pointed to by the return value of getenv() may be statically
>          allocated, and can be modified by a subsequent call to getenv().*

This implies that the value queried may be copied and a reference to the copy is returned, so the address returned *might* differ from the address where the original env-var-tuple is stored.

Comment: what does 'reentrant' have to do with the question?

Comment: @alk While the man page does say that, and some really ancient OSes did do that, no OS currently in use ever does. This answer is *not* the reason for observed behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Both addresses are correct for their memory at that time in their process. It's usually the environment size as GDB adds couple items.

But what you can try is to "unset environment LINES" and I think "unset environment COLUMNS" -- and then your env should be the same as the shell that started it.

It's usually off by those two variables when either is launched, not at the same time, from the same shell with ASLR "OFF".

Also, compile with to turn off some protections as well if you're attempting buffer overflow exploits.

```
gcc -g -z execstack -fno-stack-protector -o main main.c
```